# In Jupyter Labs 3.4.3, using find, deletes the cell output and the cell

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a multi cell notebook/workspace. After running a particular cell, I get several hundred lines of output. I then cntrl-f to open find. When I start typing my search argument into find, "test.txt", the cell that was just run and the output disappear.  They are not hidden, nor collapsed.  I have gone to checkpoints to recover. Now I save and export my workspace and just copy the cell(s) back in when the cannibalization happens. Longtime Python, short time Jupyter user.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Would you be able to prepare a a reproducible example (notebook + instructions)? I would be happy to take a closer look, ideally if you could open an issue at https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab - thank you!

Comment: Thank you @krassowski.  I figured it out and will edit the body of the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: So Jupyter Labs is looking ahead for you as you type a search word the search box. It also does something else. If it finds a match it takes your cursor there. Say I type "t" then "e" on my way to type the word "text". Labs looks ahead and sees a "te" in the code and output in the cells. It then pulls your cursor out of the search box and sets it on that "te". The "te" that my cursor flew to happened to be in output (which threw me into command mode) but I'm still typing the word "text" in the search box as far as I know. My next letter was an "x". I'm in command mode in the output and type an "x" ... which deletes the cell! Gone! I don't even see this happening because I'm looking at the search box or my keyboard. Then I hit "x" a few more times because it's not showing in the search box, so I'm just merrily deleting more cells. Type really fast or your cursor gets ripped out from underneath you.

Easy to recreate, for me at least.

Comment: Well that's what I thought. If your original example was "text" I would have pointed you to https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12723 - in short this is not intended behaviour and was already fixed (but not yet released, maybe this week?)